# La matriz no se registra correctamente en la base de datos Mysql/PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente formulario a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic en el botón "Incluir nuevo color", el formulario se replica para registrar nuevos valores. el problema es que me gustaría registrar el color básico dentro de la tabla de las fotos de los productos. Para eso, estoy tratando de hacerlo de esta manera. Pondré solo los dos campos que estoy usando:

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="CoresBasicas[]" class="form-control">
<?php 
...
 while ($jmMostrar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlMostrar))
        {
            $selected = ($key == $jmMostrar->IdCores)?("selected"):(null);
            $mostrar .= "<option value='".$jmMostrar->IdCores."' ".$selected.">".$jmMostrar->Cores."</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="text-left">
            <label for="fotos" class="upload">Selecionar fotos: <small>(Para selecionar mais de uma foto, mantenha o CTRL pressionado!)</small></label>
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="GradesFotos[]" value="'.$grades.'"> -->
            <input id="fotos" type="file" name="Fotos[]['<?php echo $grades; ?>']" multiple>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Y me estoy registrando de la siguiente manera:

```
for($f = 0; $f < count($fotos["name"]); $f++)
 { 
   foreach($fotos['name'][$f] as $key => $value)
   {
     // Aqui pego as fotos e jogo para o diretório e posteriormente cadastro no banco de dados
     mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('".$idProduto."','".$coresBasicas[$f]."','".$key."','".$nomeFotoProd."');");
   }
}
```

El problema está exactamente en el registro. Está registrando los colores solo en las dos primeras líneas y no de acuerdo con la cantidad de fotos. Por ejemplo: He subido 5 fotos con los colores blanco (ID 3) y negro (ID 9). Tenga en cuenta que los colores solo se registraron en las dos primeras líneas. Ver:

```
INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','3','11','bb4eaa294577448a3b97834eb8260524.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','9','11','e9f2776d96a508015a74673ce2e0f755.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','','13','91827d9b8e1b9f47e15a069b5dc05d1f.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','','13','b10721f5b6e8dd037394b59b32913c66.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','','13','fd4aa6b757d4d35a55a1fa6e5ab7bc79.png');
```

Pongo a continuación manualmente como debe ser:

```
INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','3','11','bb4eaa294577448a3b97834eb8260524.jpg');
    
INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','3','11','e9f2776d96a508015a74673ce2e0f755.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','9','13','91827d9b8e1b9f47e15a069b5dc05d1f.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','9','13','b10721f5b6e8dd037394b59b32913c66.jpg');

INSERT INTO loja_fotos_produtos(IdProdutos,IdCores,IdGrades,Fotos) VALUES('10','9','13','fd4aa6b757d4d35a55a1fa6e5ab7bc79.png');
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Agradezco a cualquiera que pueda ayudar. Lo siento, mi español.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Pon un ejemplo de los `select option` que se están produciendo en el contexto de tu código. Muéstranos también qué arroja un `var_dump($fotos);`  y un `var_dump($coresBasicas);`

Comment: Hola A.Cedano. El var_dump($coresBasicas) devuelve `string(1) "6" string(1) "5" NULL NULL NULL NULL`.  Las fotos se están registrando correctamente.

Comment: Ese resultado es extraño, ¿no pone algo que diga `array`? Por otra parte, hay varios valores ahí que son `NULL`, ¿qué debería haber en lugar de esos valores según tú?